# ForEach Array that prints number 1-200

Tags: php

im trying to create something that allows me in a ForEach 
to create each time different a number.

Eg:
1
TEAM24SEVEN | 1395LP | 159Wins | 51Losses
2
Gilius 1v9 | 1315LP | 148Wins | 62Losses
3
FNC Sp1rit | 1204LP | 135Wins | 45Losses

Here is my code i need to implement it in:

```
<?php 

$rank = 0+1; 
$entries = $getchallengerleaguerankingList->entries;
usort($entries, function($a,$b){
return $b->leaguePoints-$a->leaguePoints;
});

foreach($entries as $statSummaryz){
print '<p>'.$rank.'</p><p><b>' .$statSummaryz->playerOrTeamName. '</b> | <font color="blue">' .$statSummaryz->leaguePoints. '</font>LP | <font color="green">' .$statSummaryz->wins. '</font>Wins | <font color="red">' .$statSummaryz->losses.'Losses </font></p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you need. Do you want to generate a sequence like 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,... ?

Comment: not clear what you're asking/trying to achieve. can you reword it?

Comment: Its for it to print out in $rank  then 1 and then when comes round again to print number 2 and etc...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increment your variable each iteration

```
foreach($entries as $statSummaryz){
    print '<p>'.$rank.'</p><p><b>' .$statSummaryz->playerOrTeamName. '</b> | <font color="blue">' .$statSummaryz->leaguePoints. '</font>LP | <font color="green">' .$statSummaryz->wins. '</font>Wins | <font color="red">' .$statSummaryz->losses.'Losses </font></p>';
    $rank++;
}
```